# Set Apk password to preserving privacy

Tags: java, android, security

I create an app , i wonder if i can set an password to my Apk just in decompiling ,so  when anyone  try to decompile the application , it will ask for the password , so that will prevent my apk from hacking and preserving my privacy .

any advice will be appreciated , thanks alot .

Comment: You're kidding, right? If not, and since you're asking for advice, I would advise you to walk through the decompilation process and figure out which part would lead to permission to decompile being asked.

Comment: @mah im not kidding , but i dont any one to check the content of my app specially my res folder , i know class will not appear in understandable manner , thanks

Comment: i dont think there is anything you can do to prevent someone from trying to decompile your app. obfuscation will help if they do, but you can't really stop someone from trying.

Comment: @androidqq6 what you're asking for is not possible. Anything you place in your APK can be determined if someone wants it badly enough. As to "class will not appear in an understandable manner" -- this is not even guaranteed. About the only thing you're safe from prying eyes on is comments in your original source code, and certain method/class/variable names if you obfuscate.

Comment: @mah please another thing , ok can i set password in the begining of my app after already installed in any device which mean for ex. it will open splash screen asking password befor go inside the app it self , is this possible .thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do that -- just make the launch activity the one that asks the password, and if the password is right, have it start the "real" activity. Be aware though that decompilation will be a way to expose your password or even subvert it completely. Also, failure to apply code or permissions to the "real" activity might enable others to write programs to skip your launch activity and go straight to the one you want to protect. The specifics of these are too large for continuation on this question though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do this.

You may use [obfuscation libraries](http://java-source.net/open-source/obfuscators) like yGuard or ProGuard, BUT:

I have tried an obfuscator with an Android-App and after obfuscation, the DEX-compiler was unable to create the Android-App.

Comment: ProGuard has released an obfuscater for android http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: ProGuard has been integrated into the Android development process for a couple of years.

Comment: Well I create GWT-Apps for cordova/phonegp. My Javscript is already obfuscted.